# How to find the smallest number in each line of numbers? Without using min()

Tags: python, list, sorting, min, minimum

So I need to find the smallest number for each row in this file which contains these numbers:

```
6,3,5
4,4,8
3,7,2
1,8,9
9,0,6
```

How would I be able to sort through each row to find the smallest number without using the built in min() or importing anything? This is what I have so far:

```
for line in input_file:
    lines = line.split(' ')
    lines = line.replace('\n',"").replace(',',"")

    for i in range(len(lines)):
        total = int(lines[i])

        print total
        if total > maximum:
            maximum = total
            print 'hey', maximum
print 'HI', maximum
```

Comment: if you can't use min you can either: a/ implement a min function yourself or b/ sort and take the first item

Comment: well first off, i would change `line.split(' ')` to `line.split(',')`....

Comment: I have that one in the replace function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use python, but here is general aproach:

```
for line in input_file:
    numbers = line.replace('\n',"").split(',')

    min = int(numbers[0])
    for num in numbers:
        n = int(num)
        if n < min:
            min = n
    print min
```

this will print minimal value for each row

Comment: It's a bit more Pythonic (and readable) to just say `for num in numbers` rather than use the `range(len())` formulation and index them. If you don't need the indices, it's preferable to iterate over the objects directly.

Answer (score 1):

### Python Function

Python has a `min()` function built in:

```
min([7,5,3,4])
```

> => 3

### Sort

This isn't recommended, but you *could* sort a list and then pick the first number. This is more computationally intensive, but doesn't use the `min()` function, if you want this for some reason. But really, the only reason you should use this is if you get a assignment for a class or something.

```
list = [7,5,3,4]
list.sort()
list[0] #=> 3
```

### Yourself

If you need to implement this yourself, the following should work:

```
for line in input_file:
    numbers = [int(i) for i in line.replace('\n',"").split(',')]
    min = numbers[0]
    for num in numbers:
        if num < min:
            min = num
    print min
```

Comment: Eh, the list comprehension is not very readable here. It would be cleaner to leave the `numbers = line.replace('\n', '').split(',')` and iterate `for num in map(int, numbers):`. Alternately (stylistically less preferable IMO but w/e), `numbers = map(int, line.replace('\n', '').split(',')`.

Comment: @HEY, if an answer worked for you, click that check mark (Lashane did it in a bit of a different way, if you like that one better). This helps other people who stumble upon this question know which is best.

Comment: @Two-Bit Alchemist: I'm a big believer in using as few lines as possible - not sure why :D

Comment: @penne12 On Python 3 at least, `for num in map(int, numbers)` is both more efficient than your code an an exactly equal number of [lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_lines_of_code). You're hardcoding two iterations of each line. Probably not _that_ big of a deal (how many numbers are on each line really?) but still technically doubling the work.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist That makes sense.